# Sending cv.imread() data to Keras model

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, keras

I'm having trouble trying to figure out how to send the data from cv.imread() to my machine learning model.

From my image reading function, I get a list of numpy arrays which contain the images with dimension (256, 256, 3).

```py
# image reading
res_img = []
for i in files:
    img = cv2.imread(os.path.join("temp", i))
    res = cv2.resize(img, (256, 256))
    res_img.append(res)
return res_img
```

This is then stored in a dataframe and sent to the model. However, the dataframe is detected as having dimension (56, 1) where 56 is the length of my data, and 1 because each numpy array is detected as 1 object.

```py
# train model
model = create_model(trainX)
model_history = model.fit(trainX, trainY, validation_data=(testX, testY), epochs=..., batch_size=...)
```

```py
# create model
def create_model(data):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=4, activation='relu', input_shape=(256, 256, 3)))
    ...
    return model
```

However, this returns

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (56, 1)
```

The other thing I tried was to combine all the numpy arrays within the data into a large numpy array, which did have the correct dimensions

```py
trainX_arr = []
trainX = trainX.to_numpy()
for i in trainX:
    trainX_arr.append(i)
    trainX_arr = np.asarray(trainX_arr)
```

This does give the correct shape:

```py
print(trainX_arr.shape)
# (56, 256, 256, 3)
```

However, when sending to model it returns

```
ValueError: No data provided for "conv2d_input". Need data for each key in: ['conv2d_input']
```

Which I assume is because the input is not a dataframe. Finally I tried to combine the numpy arrays in the first step then store it in a dataframe, like so

```py
res_img = []
for i in files:
    img = cv2.imread(os.path.join("temp", i))
    res = cv2.resize(img, (256, 256))
    res_img.append(res)
img_arr = []
for i in res_img:
    img_arr.append(i)
    img_arr = np.asarray(img_arr)
return img_arr
```

However, when trying to insert it into a dataframe:

```py
df.insert(0, "x", img_arr)
```

It returns

```
ValueError: Wrong number of dimensions. values.ndim != ndim [4 != 2]
```

Which I assume is because the dataframe cannot hold a multi-dimensional array, but this brings me back to where I started. I am really confused as to what I should actually do in order to get this to work, and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what kind of object is `df`? please provide Minimal working example

Comment: df is a pandas dataframe

Comment: Do you have to convert it do dataframe? if not, you could just train with the number matrix that gives the correct shape: `trainX`

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work, where my 2nd method which combined the numpy arrays into a large array with valid dimensions was able to successfully train a model. I'm not sure why it did not work previously, but here is my code that works:

Defined a function (arbitrarily called numpyfy) in order to perform this array combining

```py
import os

import cv2
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from keras.layers import Conv2D, Dense, Flatten, MaxPooling2D
from keras.engine.input_layer import Input
from keras.models import Model
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split


# download images
def process_link(link_list):
    counter = 0
    for i in link_list:
        if i.find("jpg") != -1:
            ext = ".jpg"
        elif i.find("png") != -1:
            ext = ".png"
        f = open(os.path.join("temp", str(counter) + ext), "wb")
        f.write(requests.get(i).content)
        f.close()
        counter += 1
    files = os.listdir("temp") # images stored in temp directory
    res_img = []
    for i in files:
        img = cv2.imread(os.path.join("temp", i))
        res = cv2.resize(img, (256, 256))
        res_img.append(res)
    return res_img

# process data
def process_data():
    # link_list and y are a list of: links to images, and data labels, respectively
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    df.insert(0, "Y", y])
    df.insert(0, "img", process_link(link_list))
    (train, test) = train_test_split(clean_df, test_size=0.25, random_state=42)
    return (train, test)

# numpy array combining
def numpyfy(df):
    arr = []
    df_numpy = df.to_numpy()
    print(df_numpy[:2])
    for i in df_numpy:
        arr.append(i)
    arr = np.asarray(arr)
    #print(arr.shape), returns 4 dimensional array
    return arr

# Deep learning model, changed to use the Functional API
def create_model():
    input1 = Input(shape=(256, 256, 3))
    conv1 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=(3, 256, 256), activation="relu")(inpu1)
    pool1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv1)
    conv2 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation="relu")(pool1)
    pool2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv2)
    flat1 = Flatten()(pool2)
    dense1 = Dense(16, activation="relu")(flat1)
    dense2 = Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")(dense1)
    model = Model(inputs=input1, outputs=dense2)
    model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adadelta', metrics=['mse', 'mae'])
    return model

# train model
def train_model():
    (train, test) = process_data() #Returns 2 dataframes (train, test)
    train_img, test_img = numpyfy(train["img"]), numpyfy(test["img"])
    model = create_model()
    model.fit(train_img, train["Y"], validation_data=(test_img, test["Y"]),
            epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size)
```

In the end I'm not sure what I did differently that did not throw an error, but this works.